# how this code work ?? and what is the right code

Tags: php, date, time

This is my current code that doesn't seem to work correctly.

`echo date("h:i", 1*60*60) ; /*  1*60*60 mean 1 hours  right */`

The result is 03:00 when it should be 01:00.

Where is this going wrong?

**i want to do this**

1- employee come in time  admin select it

2- employee come - leave saved in mysql as timestamp

Now I'm trying to make admin see how many hours user late 
mean

user       date           time       default       late

user1      11-09-2011     09:10        09:00        10 min

user1      12-09-2011     08:00        09:00        -60 min

Comment: What do you want to do? You can pass parameters to `date()` to get your data/time cleanly

Comment: no time zone not used , how to use it  to be like this code

Comment: [`echo date_default_timezone_get();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) gives?

Comment: I'm confused by this question. If you want `01:00`, why not just `echo '01:00'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you output just `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",0)` you should see that it's not `1970-01-01 00:00:00` as it should be. It's because `date` is affected by your local timezone. For example I'm in GMT +3, and `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` gives me `1970-01-01 03:00:00`.

So the answer is you are not in GMT timezone (probably in GMT+2), and `date` is affected by it.

**UPDATE**

The following code outputs `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, so it's definitely time zones.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 0);
```

Hovewer, I can't see any mention about it in PHP's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual.

Comment: Doesn't `date()` default to using the current timestamp?

Comment: Actually, `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` (without the second parameter) defaults to the current time (the value of `time()`), not the UNIX epoch.

Comment: @Phil, it does. :) `... using the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is given`

Comment: @Phil yeah, English is not my native, and I always get confused with this :). Thanks :)

Comment: thank you all who tried to help , my problem solved with this answer   date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to your timezone (looks like GMT+2).

Date calculations in PHP are based on the configured server timezone. For example mine shows

```
$ php -r 'echo date("h:i", 3600), PHP_EOL;'

11:00
```

Comment: yes thats right , now my script work in egypt +2 in time                 if script transfered to usa ( example +6 )          how to make my code work same in any place

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in [date()](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function must be [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), seconds passed from Jan 1 1970. You need to make time according to that value.

Answer (score 0):

Err, if I'm right, date()'s second param is a unix timestamp, so the seconds since 1970.
You have to get time() and add 60*60 to it.

```
echo date("h:i", time()+60*60); // get current timestamp, add one hour
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not setup [time zones](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), which should produce a PHP warning or notice if omitted.

Comment: I'd argue on the contrary. It looks like the OP's server is configured to GMT+2

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that what SamarLover think he wants is

```
gmdate("h:i", 1 * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: Thank you @Cameron Laird , your answer is very good , and i will use it too :)

Comment: You are welcome, SamarLover; I'm gratified to know explicitly that that helps you.